# Average since beginning of the year

Tags: mysql, sql, average, moving-average

I have a MySQL table shown in a picture. The result I want to get is in the "average" column:

[image: my_table]

I would like create query to calculate the average value since the beginning of the year (1 January). Each row contains the average between the beginning of the year and current row. Each 1 January the average should be reset to zero.

Comment: create a SQLfiddle ( http;//www.sqlfiddle.com ) you will get more help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select date, value,
       (select avg(value) from t t2 where t2.date <= t.date) as running_avg
from t
order by date;
```

This makes some assumptions:

- "a", "b" and so on are numbers, not strings.
- `a+b/2` really means `(a + b) / 2` and so on.
- If you need from only this year, then the condition needs to include the year.

Comment: shouldn't the outer query include a `ORDER BY date ASC`

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . I supposed so, but that has no effect on the running average.

Comment: This work fine for me. Thanks! I added needed year to "where" conditions and I received the expected results :)